# Genymotion Crash after a few minutes

Tags: android, genymotion

I have built a demo application which works perfectly, and looks like the following:

[image: working]

Then after a few runs, Genymotion suddenly stops working, and a screen like the following appears:

[image: not working].

The Logcat keeps recording the following lines:

```
05-25 13:58:24.326: E/eglCodecCommon(2163): writeFully: failed: Broken pipe
05-25 13:58:24.418: E/EGL_genymotion(2163): tid 2163: eglChooseConfig(544): error 0x3001 (EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163): Process: com.nextgenintl.aimassistant, PID: 2163
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: eglChooseConfig failed EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.chooseEglConfig(HardwareRenderer.java:1173)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.loadEglConfig(HardwareRenderer.java:1135)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initializeEgl(HardwareRenderer.java:1117)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.initialize(HardwareRenderer.java:1057)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-25 13:58:24.422: E/AndroidRuntime(2163):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I shut down Genymotion and relaunch it, it works fine again.

What is the cause of this problem, and is anyone experiencing it too?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not really caused by your application, so don't worry.

It often happens when you computer goes in sleep mode and when you come back Genymotion will throw this exception (it happens to me very often).

In your specific case sounds like the device goes in sleep mode so a way to fix it is simply to enable "Always stay awake" in developers options.

[image]

Another way to fix it is just to turn off your emulator and relaunch. (as you already do)

Comment: Is the problem caused by the IP change then?

Comment: Personally i don't have idea why it happens, maybe Genymotion developers team could help you more (but why lose time for this? genymotion emulator is so fast to launch that i don't really care if happens)

Comment: Thank a lot. I'm searching for this problem and I found this answer. It's work with me.

Answer (score 0):

The broken pipe error means there is a problem with the connection between emulator and host computer.

To fix it you can restart the emulator (or follow the advice from the other answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it choosing the same resolution of my virtual device. It says "Custom Tablet - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 2560x1600" and the resolution was lower than this. When I put the same, the device doesn't crash anymore